# nginx url rewrite blesta

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting

Could someone help me convert this URL rewrite

```
########################################################
# package:    minPHP
# filename:   .htaccess
########################################################

<Files ~ "\.(pdt)$">
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
</Files>

# Protect against Clickjacking
#Header append X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"

RewriteEngine on

# Force HTTPS
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/install.php$
RewriteRule install.php %1/install/ [R=301,L]
```

Here is our current rewrite it works fine but a few errors. such as /index.php/ still being there in the links when it should be /client/login and some pages forces you to download a file labled "download"

```
# Disallow access to any file with .pdt extension
  location ~ (\.pdt) {
    return 403;
  }

  location / {
  error_page     404 = @blesta; #IF file doesn't exist
  log_not_found  off;

  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;

  # For access to install file
  if ($request_uri ~ "^(.*)/install.php$"){
    rewrite install.php /%1/install/ redirect;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Forgot to mention. when I load /index.php/ it works fine but when I load it via / it asks me to download a file called download

Answer (score 1):

The nginx rewrite rules for blesta:
https://github.com/cloudrck/blesta-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/blestav3

How to remove /index.php/ in URL:

Edit lib/init.php, change:

```
define("HTACCESS", file_exists(ROOTWEBDIR . ".htaccess"));
```

To:

```
define("HTACCESS", true);
```

ref: http://docs.blesta.com/display/user/Installing+Blesta#InstallingBlesta-SystemConfiguration